# Sonarqube not generating Technical debt data (Debt and Issues) when connecting to Oracle

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I can run SonarQube without any database and works fine.

When i configure below properties in file sonar.properties to use Oracle
database then the scan is not generating Technical debt data (Debt and 
Issues).Duplications and Structure information is coming up correctly.

```
sonar.jdbc.username=    
sonar.jdbc.password=     
sonar.jdbc.url=
```

Is there any config which I need to enable when using external database?

I am using SonarQube 5.4 and SonarQube Scanner 2.6. Using ojdbc6_g.jar for Oracle drivers.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There's hardly any relation between the database used and the measures reported by the analysis. Please share more details about the scan itself (scanner log and [background task log](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Background+Tasks)) and point at what you believe is incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Ran sonar-scanner -X. When connected to external database (Oracle)  Line stating DEBUG: Exploring Exploded Graph for method doesn't appear anywhere whereas it does appear few times when using embedded database.